# AWS Lambda Endpoint request timed out Snowflake Connection in Python taking long time to connect

Tags: aws-lambda, python-3.6, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

While querying the AWS Lambda API Gateway, I am getting Endpoint request timed out. AWS Lambda is written using Snowflake Python Connector and Python version is 3.6 and AWS Lambda is creating snowflake connection and querying snowflake for the data

```
conn = snowflake.connector.connect(
    user=sf_user,
    password=sf_pwd,
    account=sf_acc,
    warehouse=sf_warehouse,
    database=sf_db,
    schema=sf_schema
)
```

This line is taking more than 50 seconds as a result of which the AWS API Gateway is giving Endpoint request timed out response

Comment: What happens when you run that code locally, or on EC2 or something? Does it still take over 50 seconds? Also, is the Lambda function configured to run in a VPC?

Comment: It takes little over 20 seconds during connection locally.

Comment: If you run the Lambda manually, directly instead of through API Gateway, does the connection eventually happen? I'm trying to help you determine if this is a network configuration issue, or if this is just too slow to work in Lambda. You didn't answer my VPC question.

Comment: Yes, Connection is successful every time as I can see the data printed in CloudWatch Console and Lambda is configured to run in a VPC.

Comment: Have you tried increasing the amount of memory for the Lambda function to the maximum? That also increases the amount of CPU available, which could make this run faster.

Comment: I tried increasing memory to 3008 MB from existing value of 1024 MB, but the connection is still taking time. I also configured lambda function to use No VPC but the results are same.

Comment: Not sure how you are populating those variables on the connection within your Lambda function, but is it possible that they are incorrect?  Maybe grab a print() statement of the connection string to be sure?

Answer (score 1):

Kindly refer to this documentation first: https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/How-to-Use-Snowflake-with-AWS-Lambda
There are many factors which are collectively creating such slowdown. Few of which you can address are:

- Same Region of your lambda code and the region of snowflake.
- Turn off the connector console logging, refer this https://stackoverflow.com/a/61153054/9073711
- Increase the size of your snowflake warehouse.

In addition, If there are multiple queries, you could certainly make a thread-pool/process-pool or use asyncIO if its **not on AWS Lamda**. You pay for execution per second on lambda, and for every request creating a connection and destroying it is an overhead. You should create a service using any ASGI framework and then wrap the snowflake connection for single or multiple queries in every request. Hope this helps :-)